# How to call IQueryable.OrderBy() method with a runtime type for generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I need to call the `OrderBy<T, TKey>(Func<T, TKey>)` method with a value for `TKey` only available at runtime. After reading answers on SO on how to use a variable as a generic parameter, I'm trying the following approach:

```
string key = "MyProperty";
Type keyType = typeof(T).GetProperty(key).PropertyType;
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass)
                .GetMethod(
                    "MyGenericStaticMethod"),
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
// T is known at compile time.
MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), keyType});

var expression = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { params });

myQueryable.OrderBy(expression);
```

The problem is, `genericMethodInfo.Invoke()` returns `object` and hence cannot be used with `OrderBy()` which expects an argument of type `Func<T, TKey>`. However, `TKey` can be different value types like `string`,`int` that are only known at runtime. Can this even be done and if so, how?

Comment: what are you trying to achive? You may ommit generic parameters like this: `someList.OrderBy(x => x.MyProperty)`.

Comment: I'm trying to pass an `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` instead of the hard-coded lambda expression.

Comment: can you please add a sample code of how you would like to use this?

Comment: My project https://www.nuget.org/packages/OrderByString/ creates the lambda expression you refer to behind the scenes, based on the string value of the property to sort by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `MethodInfo.Invoke()` is used to perform method call with provided parameters, and cannot be used to generate expression. To generate lambda `Expression` that can be used as an argument to `.OrderBy()` method, use this instead:

```
string key = "MyProperty";
Type keyType = typeof(T).GetProperty(key).PropertyType;
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethod(
    "MyGenericStaticMethod",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), keyType });

//this represents parameter of keySelector expression used in OrderBy method
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

// Expression representing call to MyGenericStaticMethod
var expression = Expression.Call(genericMethodInfo, parameterExpression);

// To use it as an argument of OrderBy method, we must convert expression to lambda
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expression, parameterExpression);
```

You will probably encounter another problem: You cannot simply call `myQueryable.OrderBy(lambda)`, because this doesn't allow compiller to infer it's generic arguments and you cannot provide these generic arguments, because `TKey` is not known at compile time. So you will need to do another reflection, to actually call an `.OrderBy()` method:

```
// OrderBy method has generic parameters and several overloads. It is thus 
// difficult to get it's MethodInfo just by typeof(Queryable).GetMethod().
// Although it may seem weird, but it is easier to get it's MethodInfo from
// some arbitrary expression. Generic arguments "<object, object>" does not
// matter for now, we will replace them later
Expression<Func<IQueryable<object>, IQueryable<object>>> orderByExpression =
    x => x.OrderBy<object, object>((o) => null);

// Replace generic parameters of OrderBy method with actual generic arguments
var orderByMethodInfo = (orderByExpression.Body as MethodCallExpression)
    .Method
    .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), keyType });

// Now we are finally ready to call OrderBy method
var orderedResultQuery = orderByMethodInfo.Invoke(
    null,
    new Object[] { myQueryable, lambda })
    as IQueryable<T>;

// Just for testing purpose, let's materialize result to list
var orderedResult = orderedResultQuery.ToList();
```